# Struggle with getting ID from user

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

My idea to make is to make an unique ID for each user. It contains both chars and integrers. First 2 letter of ID will be initials of users name, 4 next ones must be year, and 3 last ones are random.

```
public String getUserID(){
    String[] ID = new String[9];
    ID[0] = String.valueOf(name.charAt(1));
    ID[1] = String.valueOf(surname.charAt(2));
    int years = Date_Of_Birth.getYear();
    int[] numOfYears = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int a = years%10;
        a = numOfYears[i];
        years /= 10;
        ID[i] = numOfYears[i]; // Java.lang.string, not int
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int a = Integer.toString(random.nextInt(9)); // Java.lang.string, not int
    int b = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
    int c = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
    ID[7] = a;
    ID[8] = b;
    ID[9] = c;

}
```

I am struggling with changing integrers to strings, and also the other way around. I've been trying few things like String.valueOf() or integers, but it all seems hopeless

Comment: You can use `Integer.toString(int)`

Comment: Can you be more precise about what issues you're having with `String.valueOf(int)` and `Integer.valueOf( String)`?

Comment: One issue I think you're having is that you have an array of string `String[] ID = new String[9]` but that gives you *nine different strings*.  Probably what you want is just one string for the ID, and you should use concatenation ( "string" + "one" ) or a `StringBuilder` to get your ID string.

Comment: With both IDEA shows that those are incompatibile types, required is int, and given is java.lang.string.

Comment: I will try building one string!

Comment: Changed it a little bit as @markspace suggested. Instead of going for full ID as a Array i grouped it into smaller Arrays and ints and sumed them as a whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to construct just one `String` instead of `String[]` array.

```
Random random = new Random();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(name.charAt(1))
       .append(surname.charAt(2))
       .append(Date_Of_Birth.getYear())
       .append(100 + random.nextInt(900)));
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but wouldn't `random.nextInt(900)` return max 900? And 900 + 100 = 1000, which means there is a chance the last string append will be 4 characters instead of 3?

Comment: @cokeby190 the upper bound `900` is not inclusive so the call returns numbers [0, 899] as per [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)).

Comment: oh right got it! This is a really cool way of doing 3 digit random number though! (:

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
public String getUserID(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(name.substring(0, 1));
    sb.append(surname.substring(0, 1));
    sb.append(String.valueOf(Date_Of_Birth.getYear()));

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        int a = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        sb.append(String.valueOf(a));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

it uses `SringBuilder` to build the id step by step:

- appends the 1st char of `name`
- appends the 1st char of `surname`
- appends the year (provided it's 4 digits that are returned by `Date_Of_Birth.getYear()`)
- inside a loop appends 3 single digit random numbers
- returns the string of `StringBuilder`

Comment: The algorithm does no guarantee a unique user id. You should also check whether the user id already exists, and repeat generating random numbers until you obtain a unique user id. It might also be that 3 digits are not enough, for example if the user name is James Smith or whatever is currently a very popular name. [Most common names](https://blogs.ancestry.com/cm/calling-james-smith-10-most-common-first-and-surname-combinations/)

Comment: @JonathanRosenne of course it doesn't. This is just the OP's way of getting an id.

Answer (score 0):

After changes the code looks like this, as far as i'm concerned I thinks it's okay.

```
public String getUserID(){
        String[] IDletters = new String[2];
        IDletters[0] = String.valueOf(name.charAt(1));
        IDletters[1] = String.valueOf(surname.charAt(2));
        int years = Date_Of_Birth.getYear();
        int[] numOfYears = new int[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int a = years%10;
            a = numOfYears[i];
            years /= 10;
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        int a = random.nextInt(9)+1;
        int b = random.nextInt(9)+1;
        int c = random.nextInt(9)+1;
        String wholeID = IDletters[0]+IDletters[1]+numOfYears[0]+numOfYears[1]+numOfYears[2]+numOfYears[3]+ a + b + c;
        return wholeID;

    }
```